# Fields not evaluated in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 9.6. I want to count the number of times a value is between two other values within a column.

In this example, I am searching the “mid” column and the result should be 5. It works fine if I hardcode the values but that is not acceptable. It fails when using field values giving an answer of 20. It appears to ignore the low and high fields altogether.

Why are the “low” and “high” fields not evaluated in the second case statement??? And how do I get around it?

```
SELECT low, mid, high,
        sum(case when mid between 35  and 57   then 1 end) over(partition by mid between 35  and 57) as "StaticNums",
        sum(case when mid between low and high then 1 end) over(partition by mid between low and high) as "non-StaticNums"
FROM
    (SELECT l-11 as low, l as mid, l+11 as high
        FROM generate_series(1,100,5) as l(n)
        group by l.n
     ) as t
group by mid, low, high
order by mid
```

I added a pic of what the results I’m looking for using excel. In short, I want each row to count how many widgets are within a given range (using the low & high values and mid as the widgets). 
But how do I do this in sql?

[Excel image showing example of what I'd like to accompish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zu1A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your first CASE statement counts how many times MID is between 35 and 57, and then displays that result on rows that are between 35 and 57. (The result is 5, and it shows that value on those five rows).
The second CASE statement counts how many times MID is between LOW and HIGH, and then displays that result on every row where that is true.  There are 20 rows, and in every row the condition is met, so it displays 20 on every row.
So your code appears to be doing what you say you want it to do, and that's what shows in your screenshot.  If you want "StaticNums" to show '5' in every row, then your partition shouldn't reduce to only the rows that contributed to the condition, so try this code:

```
SELECT low, mid, high,
        sum(case when mid between 35  and 57   then 1 end) over(partition by 1 = 1) as "StaticNums",
        sum(case when mid between low and high then 1 end) over(partition by mid between low and high) as "non-StaticNums"
FROM
    (SELECT l-11 as low, l as mid, l+11 as high
        FROM generate_series(1,100,5) as l(n)
        group by l.n
     ) as t
group by mid, low, high
order by mid
```

Comment: Thanks tysonwright for your quick reply. The results I get with partition 1=1 in the first case statement is each row displays the value of 5. I understand now your explanation of why the 2nd statement displays 20 on each row.  The result I'm looking for is 2nd case to look like the 1st case in the picture. I'm still lost on how to achieve that. Your thoughts are indeed welcome.

Comment: Then change the second CASE to use "partition by mid between 35 and 57" as well.

Comment: The problem is those numbers are hardcoded. I don't know what those numbers will be in the actual table. Let me explain a little more; The actual table only has a mid value and a percentage value per row. The percentage value could be something like 10%, 15% etc.. Which I use to create a +/- range from the mid value - In this case the low and high. So I don't know what the low and high will actually be. The goal is to count how many mid column values are within a +/- range for each row.  I hope I explained that well...

Comment: So, without much more clarity regarding your logic, and maybe better test data that more completely emulates what you're trying to do, the best I can offer is that you need to "partition by {whatever logic determines which rows you want the results to appear on}".

Comment: Yeah, I think I’m making this too complicated. I edited the original comment and added a picture to help envision the desired results. Please take a look at the excel pic. Hopefully, it better explains my objective.